Failed to make calls: Arkesel Error: A 'contents' key is required
Trying to make voice sms with arkesel but anytime I run the command I get this error
"Failed to make calls: Arkesel Error: A 'contents' key is required"
I tried adding this `->asMultipart()` because testing the endpoint with postman using the form-data with 'voice_file'(which I uploaded to the postman) and 'recipients[]'(which was a phone number), it works in the postman
  public function makeCall($recipients)
    {
        $filePath = storage_path('app/public/assets/harvard.wav');

        // Check if the file exists
        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
            throw new Exception("Audio file not found at {$filePath}");
        }

        try {
            $response = Http::withHeaders([
                'api-key' => $this->apiKey
            ])
                ->attach('voice_file', fopen($filePath, 'r'), 'harvard.wav') // Attach the audio file
                ->post('https://sms.arkesel.com/api/v2/sms/voice/send', [
                    'recipients' => $recipients,
                ]);

            // Check for successful response
            if ($response->successful()) {
                Log::info("Voice SMS sent successfully with Arkesel: ", ['recipients' => $recipients, 'response' => $response->json()]);
                return $response->json();
            } else {
                Log::error("Voice SMS failed: ", ['recipients' => $recipients, 'error' => $response->body()]);
                throw new Exception("Arkesel Error: " . $response->body());
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error("Voice SMS failed with exception: ", ['recipients' => $recipients, 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
            throw new Exception("Arkesel Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }```



<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

public function makeCall($recipients)
{
    $filePath = 'C:/Users/Dex/Downloads/native.mp3';
    $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    // Set up logging
    $log = new Logger('voice_sms');
    $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('sms.log', Logger::DEBUG));

    // Check if the file exists
    if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
        throw new Exception("Audio file not found at {$filePath}");
    }

    // Set up Guzzle client
    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $response = $client->post('https://sms.arkesel.com/api/v2/sms/voice/send', [
            'headers' => [
                'api-key' => $apiKey,
            ],
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'recipients[]',
                    'contents' => implode(',', $recipients) // Convert array to comma-separated string
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'voice_file',
                    'contents' => fopen($filePath, 'r'),
                    'filename' => 'native.mp3'
                ]
            ],
            'http_errors' => false,
            'timeout' => 0,
            'allow_redirects' => [
                'max' => 10,
                'strict' => true,
                'protocols' => ['http', 'https']
            ],
        ]);

        // Check for successful response
        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
            $log->info("Voice SMS sent successfully with Arkesel", ['recipients' => $recipients, 'response' => $data]);
            return $data;
        } else {
            $log->error("Voice SMS failed", ['recipients' => $recipients, 'error' => $response->getBody()->getContents()]);
            throw new Exception("Arkesel Error: " . $response->getBody()->getContents());
        }
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        $log->error("Voice SMS failed with exception", ['recipients' => $recipients, 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        throw new Exception("Arkesel Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}





You should explain a bit with the code you provided.
